# I found a website that lists all the email addresses of Facebook users in UK. What do I do?

Tags: data-leakage, confidentiality

I came across this very peculiar website that supposedly lists the email addresses of Facebook users in the UK. I will not be posting the URL for obvious reasons.

I entered a couple of emails to see if they were real and the ones I checked were actually real.

What do I do with this information?

The original website does not exist anymore (closed in 2013). It has been archived on the [Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/web/).

There are 35000 pages with 1000 accounts each. It is impossible for me to check if my account is also listed. It really seems that all Facebook users in the UK have their personal username and e-mail exposed.

Should I put up the URL?
 [Image](https://imgur.com/gallery/r4E8oSI)

Comment: What do you *want* to do? What are the possible outcomes that you foresee? Do you want to have the info removed? Do you think it should be released to the media for exposure? Do you want the original site owners to be punished? I'm not sure where you want to go with this.

Comment: Do you want to know what to do to protect yourself? Do you want to report it to someone? Do you want it taken down? Do you want to profit from it? Like, what do you want to *do*?

Comment: I had earlier misinterpreted the answer that I had accepted.It seems to be a leak certsinly as allUK Facebook users have their e-mail adresses exposed.I want to bring it to the attention of the respective authorities,not Facebook.The site has been shut down in 2013.

Comment: Then you need to report to the ICO for the protection of the people involved. If it is a malicious leak, then you might need to report to the UK police (try ActionFraud). Someone with knowledge of this type of things needs to understand the situation to know how to deal with it. I'm happy to provide my personal details so I can better direct you. Without details, we can only give generic answers.

Comment: Check out a google search for that data: https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GIGM_enGB836&ei=ZNBmXN2-D8bSkgX5u4OgBw&q=%2235+million+Facebook+names+and+accounts+of+people%22&oq=%2235+million+Facebook+names+and+accounts+of+people%22&

Comment: Whoops,it has to be a new development cause when I had checked I had received unrelated reports.So if this is the case,can anything be done,sinve most of these websites have been taken down?

Comment: Again "things do be done" is relative. Contact Archive.org

Comment: Shall be doing so shortly.

Comment: I think it would also be useful to pass this information to Troy Hunt at HaveIBeenPwned in case it's an actual leak

Answer (score 1):

To me this looks like a leak and someone uploaded it there. It's safe to assume that not only did this one person upload it to various sites but also that others already downloaded it. It's out there and even tho the specific website you mentioned might be taken down it's not possible to un-publish this. It's already out there. You can ask yourself personally how bad this e-mail leak is for you (I assume you're in the list). Maybe you're receiving lots of Spam. Or maybe nothing happens at all.

No facebook-specific advice can be given but personally I'd say when you are concerned about this then start using different mail accounts for different services. Some mail services allow you to create many mail addresses and look at them in an aggregated view. Once mail addresses behave weird (e. g. receive lots of spam) then maybe you want to rotate addressed for that specific service and/or stop using that service.

Comment: site is no longer active - the OP found this data on the WaybackMachine

Comment: The question is not what to do as someone who's info has been disclosed but rather what to do having discovered this database of personal information.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what the source of these emails might be. It could be a leak from Facebook. It could be users who deliberately published their emails and got them scraped. It could be from a third party source completely unrelated to Facebook.

So, what to do?

- I think the chances of the data disappearing from the internet are slim, but Archive.org might unarchive it if you contact them.
- You could report it to Facebook, since they might want to investigate if there has been some leak from them.
- You could also report it to relevant authorities in charge of data protection issues (but I don't know who those are in the UK).

Comment: the ICO is the relevant authority in the UK

Answer (score 0):

Since the original website is no longer running, the relevant website is in fact Archive.org. They are the ones listing this information.

Please contact them to let them know about the problem. They have been good in the past about removing data.

Note that Archive.org is a US company and not subject to GDPR (yes, there are "agreements" that wax and wane from month to month, but it's easier to assume that the US is not required to be compliant). The ICO is the body in the UK who might be interested, depending on a lot of details.

Comment: The problem is that I do not have a lot of details.All I have is their profile name and their emails.There is no "about" or "contact" page whereby to gain any more information.

Comment: @AlanWhitteaker wait. what? Archive.org has a contact email.

Comment: No, I mean report the Archive.org link you found with all those emails and report ***that*** to the ICO.

Comment: @AlanWhitteaker with the new data you provided, I'd contact Archive.org to request the data is taken down. My guess is that the website you found is a legitimate website for something else, but this database was lurking somewhere in it?